# Why is my model being resized every time I select the armature?

Tags: modeling, rigging, .fbx

I have a model from an FBX file that I've imported into Blender with an armature from Mixamo.
When the file imported, its scale was 0.010. I fixed that by scaling the whole "Armature" object back to 1.0 after the import.

But every time I select the model's armature, it automatically scales back down to 0.010.
Why? What could this be? Is this an FBX issue, or a bug in Blender? (My version is 2.83.1)

Here's what's happening:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fields you are trying to change are green which means they are animated by corresponding keyframes. (These keep you from changing anything that is not part of the animation, unless you add or remove keyframes).

Most likely scale is not a part of your animation and you can delete these keyframes to regain control over the scale. Right click the fields and choose Clear Keyframes.